# React onClick execute all onClick in the element

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following code in my component:

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav">
    <li className="active" onClick={this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)}><Link to="/owner.html">Main<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link></li>
    <li onClick={this.props.resetInfoAndError(2)}><Link to="/carwash">Second</Link></li>
</ul>
```

`this.props.resetInfoAndError(element)` is function that trasfer to component through redux container (`mapDispatchToProps`)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    saveInfo: (info) => {
        dispatch(changeInfo(info))
    },

    resetInfoAndError: (a) => {
        dispatch(changeInfo(a))
    }
}
}
```

I installed redux logger and press on the one `li` tag and see in console that why function is call in both tags (with 1 and 2 param):

[image]

Why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: because you are wrong assigning your function, it should be `{() => this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)}` not `{this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)}`. This `() => this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)` returns a function which executes `this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)` and this `this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)` calls a function and returns a value and that value is assigned to onClick handler

Comment: @niba Thank you, it's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the `onclick` during the render. Use a wrapper function like below.

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav">
    <li className="active" onClick={() => this.props.resetInfoAndError(1)}><Link to="/owner.html">Main<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link></li>
    <li onClick={() => this.props.resetInfoAndError(2)}><Link to="/carwash">Second</Link></li>
</ul>
```